# How do you print the key in the template?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

Say I have a values.yaml:

```
foo:
    bar:
        doo: 123
```

In my template file, I can do this:

```
{{- range .Values.foo.bar }}
- name: {{ .doo }}
{{- end }}
```

Which will print:

```
- name: 123
```

But I want to make it say:

```
- name: doo
```

Is there a way to do this?  I tried

```
{{ . }}
```

but it's not what I want because it dumps the whole object.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily grab the key and value by using the assignment:

```
{{- range $thekey, $thevalue := .Values.foo.bar }}
- name: {{ $thekey }}
{{- end }}
```